# Println a boolean value using a lambda expression

Tags: java

In java you can print a boolean value like this:

```java
System.out.println(1 == 1);
```

But if I try to achieve this using a lambda expression I got an error:

```java
System.out.println(() -> 1 == 1);  // the `() -> 1 == 1` expression should return `true`
```

Why can I not do it ?

Comment: You're trying to print the lambda, not what it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda expression must have the type of some functional interface (the interface which it implements).

Since no overload of `println` takes a functional interface as an argument, the compiler doesn't know the type of the functional interface that should be implemented by your lambda expression.

You can specify it as follows:

```
System.out.println((Supplier<Boolean>) () -> 1 == 1);
```

or

```
Supplier<Boolean> sup = () -> 1 == 1;
System.out.println(sup);
```

Of course you would be printing the functional interface instance, not the `boolean` value.

To print the `boolean` value you can write:

```
Supplier<Boolean> sup = () -> 1 == 1;
System.out.println(sup.get());
```

Comment: Oh thanks fot the great answer now I understand (was a dummy question). Thanks for the tipps of using `Supplier` and `.get`.